# Custom button - get response from REST callout

Tags: apex, webservices

I have a custom javascript button on a standard layout that performs a number of validations and then makes a synchronous REST callout via an Apex class. This all works fine, however I'd like to be able to return the reponse to the button so that I can add an Alert to the user e.g. record creation successfull/unsuccessful. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

`sforce.apex.execute("myWebservice","createRecord",{tName:"{!Opportunity.Account}")`

Comment: Does you custom rest method return anything? If not, create a response class or a string or something and return it and assign it to a var. i.e. `var response = force.apex.execute(xxxxx)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Salesforce documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm). Hope this helps

**Controller**

```
global class myClass{ 
   webService static String getContextUserName() {
        return UserInfo.getFirstName();
   }
}
```

**JS code**

```
var contextUser = sforce.apex.execute("myClass", "getContextUserName", {});
```